# Airflow dynamically genarated task not run in order

Tags: bigdata, airflow, airflow-taskflow

I have created dynamic tasks generation dag. Tasks are generated accurately, But those tasks are not trigger in order,not work in consistently.
i have noticed it triggered on alphanumeric order.
Let's check run_modification_ tasks. i have generated 0 to 29 tasks. i have noticed it trigger on below format.
*run_modification_0
run_modification_1
run_modification_10
run_modification_11
run_modification_12
run_modification_13
run_modification_14
run_modification_15
run_modification_16
run_modification_17
run_modification_18
run_modification_19
run_modification_2
run_modification_21
run_modification_23....*

**But i need to run it on tasks order like**
*run_modification_0
run_modification_1
run_modification_2
run_modification_3
run_modification_4
run_modification_5..*

**Please help me to run those tasks on task created order.**

[image: Please check related dag running image]

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
from airflow.hooks.postgres_hook import PostgresHook
from airflow.models import Variable
import os

args = {
        'owner': 'Airflow',
        'start_date': days_ago(2),
}

dag = DAG(
        dag_id='tastOrder',
        default_args=args,
        schedule_interval=None,
        tags=['task']
)

modification_processXcom = """ cd {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=\'run_modification_\'+params.i, key=\'taskDateFolder\') }}  """


def modificationProcess(ds,**kwargs):
    today  = datetime.strptime('2021-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    i = str(kwargs['i'])
    newDate = today-timedelta(days=int(i))
    print(str(newDate))
    kwargs["ti"].xcom_push("taskDateFolder", str(newDate))



def getDays():
    today = today = datetime.strptime('2021-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    yesterday = today - timedelta(days=30)
    day_Diff = today-yesterday
    return day_Diff,today

day_Diff, today = getDays()
for i in reversed(range(0,day_Diff.days)):
    run_modification = PythonOperator(
        task_id='run_modification_'+str(i),
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=modificationProcess,
        op_kwargs={'i': str(i)},
        dag=dag,
    )

    modification_processXcom = BashOperator(
        task_id='modification_processXcom_'+str(i),
        bash_command=modification_processXcom,
        params = {'i' :str(i)},
        dag = dag
    )

    run_modification >> modification_processXcom
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @Elad, Code shared

Comment: What is the structure you are looking for? `run_modification_1 -> modification_processXcom_1 -> run_modification_2 -> modification_processXcom_2 -> ... - > run_modification_29 -> modification_processXcom_29` ?

Comment: see edit to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the dependency as:

```
run_modification_1 -> modification_processXcom_1 -> 
run_modification_2 -> modification_processXcom_2 -> ... - > 
run_modification_29 -> modification_processXcom_29
```

You can do:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator


dag = DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 8, 10),
    catchup=False,
    is_paused_upon_creation=False,
)

mylist1 = []
mylist2 = []
for i in range(1, 30):
    mylist1.append(
        BashOperator( # Replace with your requested operator
            task_id=f'run_modification_{i}',
            bash_command=f"""echo executing run_modification_{i}""",
            dag=dag,
        )
    )
    mylist2.append(
        BashOperator( # Replace with your requested operator
            task_id=f'modification_processXcom_{i}',
            bash_command=f"""echo executing modification_processXcom_{i}""",
            dag=dag,
        )
    )
if len(mylist1) > 0:
    mylist1[-1] >> mylist2[-1] # This set dependency between run_modifiation to modification_processXcom
if len(mylist1) > 1:
    mylist2[-2] >> mylist1[-1] # This set dependency between modification_processXcom to previous run_modifiation
```

This code create a list of operators and set them to run one after another as:
[image]

Tree view:
[image]

Comment: Hi Elad, it's worked what i expected. Thank You